# Importing python package from conda environment in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju2A2.png)

Somebody please explain why I am not able to import package in VSCode even though I can do it in terminal both in VSCode and in system

Comment: [Ctrl][Shift][P] → Python: Select Interpreter → Select the `python` binary from your environment

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
VSCode uses multiple python binaries. Each one has a seperate list of installed modules and packages. By default VSCode uses a custom Anaconda binary. When you invoke the python command, you are using a system wide install of Anaconda. You need to change the binary version of python VSCode is using, to point at the system-wide install, where you installed your modules